# Convert bitmap to PNG or JPG using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, png, bitmap

Anyone knows how to convert a bitmap to PNG or JPG using Objective C assuming I have

CGImageRef imageRef;

Comment: Objective-C as in Mac or iPhone?

Comment: If mac, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320988/saving-cgimageref-to-a-png-file

Answer (score 7):

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
NSData *jpgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage);
```