# iOS 8 Photo Extension: transparency

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-extension

I have an app that applies transparency to areas in a photo. I want to be able to convert this app into a photos extension. However, the the photos in the photos library are in JPG. Is there anyway to convert the image to PNG either before, during, or after using my photos extension?

Comment: [Convert bitmap to PNG or JPG using Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1740691/593709) will do?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work inside a photos extension.